# Wie viele Konjunktionen hat das Deutsche

Tags: conjunction

Ich bin auf der Suche nach einer Quelle oder Antwort für folgende Fragen:

- Wie viele Konjunktionen hat das Deutsche?
- Wie viele davon sind Subjunktionen?
- Wie viele davon bestehen aus mehr als einem Wort?

Bitte keine Verweise auf die Wikipedia-Liste, denn die ist voll mit Konjunktionaladverbien.

Comment: http://deutsch.lingo4u.de/grammatik/satzbau/konditionalsaetze/konjunktionen

Comment: Wenn ich es recht überlege, ist die Konjunktion "aber" eigentlich auch ein Konunktionaladverb, kann es doch seine Position verändern. "Doch" wird von Wiktionary bereits als sowohl als auch eingestuft.

Comment: @Em1: sehr schöner Link... leider nicht annähernd komplett... es fehlen zum Beispiel: insofern, wenngleich, trotz'dem, sofern etc... ausserdem fehlen paarige und mehrteilige Konjunktionen

Comment: "trotzdem" ist rechts unten. Die anderen fehlen tatsächlich. Wenn ich es aber recht überlege, können bestimmte Worte eben mehrere Funktionen einnehmen, und damit ist es recht unwahrscheinlich, dass eine annährend treffende Liste überhaupt zu finden ist, selbst wenn jedes Wort zumindest einmal genannt würde.

Comment: Und finally, Konjunktionen aus zwei Wörter sind eigentlich nichts anderes als zwei Konjunktionen, die in Kombination eine andere Bedeutung haben (können). Sie sind aber stets für sich alleine stehend auch entw. eine Konjunktion oder ein Konjunktionaladverb. Ex. "A ist wahr, aber ich bin für B" - "A ist wahr, dennoch bin ich für B" - "A ist wahr, aber dennoch bin ich für B" - "A ist wahr und dennoch bin ich für B" - "A ist wahr und doch bin ich für B" - und mit einer anderen Bedeutung: "A ist wahr und ich bin für B"

Comment: @Em1: ich meine nicht das Adverb trotzdem sonder "Trotzdem ich müde bin, gehe ich arbeiten". Und da es bei Wikipedia ein falsche Liste gibt, warum soll es nicht irgendwo auch eine richtige Liste geben

Comment: und noch was... "es sei denn" ist meines Erachtens nach nicht aus Konjunktionen(-aladverbien) zusammengesetzt.

Comment: Genau das ist der Punkt. Du kannst ein Wort eben doch in verschiedenen Kategorieren einordnen. Der Argumentationen werden auseinander gehen. Manche sagen, eine Konjunktion muss zwingend an erster Stelle stehen. Somit ist "und" eine Konjunktion, "aber" jedoch nicht. Wenn ein Wort aber seine Wortart ändert, nur weil es wo anders steht, so ist "aber" wieder eine Konjunktion, *wenn* es vorne steht.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/10355/discussion-between-em1-and-emanuel)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Man wird nur schwer eine genaue Zahl aller Konjunktionen erhalten, dafür sind  Wortdatenbanken und Wörterbücher zu unvollständig oder zu sehr abhängig vom Ausmaß der redaktionellen Arbeit. Auch werden möglicherweise nicht oder nicht mehr gebräuchliche Konjunktionen hier einfach nicht erfasst.

Es gibt also nur Anhaltspunkte, in welcher Größenordnung sich die derzeit in der deutschen Sprache verwendeten Konjunktionen befinden.

Unten eine schnelles Suche bei zwei gängigen Wörterbüchern

#### Wiktionary

- [Konjunktionen](http://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/Kategorie%3aKonjunktion_%28Deutsch%29): **65**
- [Subjunktionen](http://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/Kategorie%3aSubjunktion_%28Deutsch%29): **35**

#### Duden

- Konjunktionen (mit Google Suche `site:www.duden.de/rechtschreibung "Wortart: Konjunktion"`): ca. **81**
  (darunter auch so seltene Konjunktionen wie *sintemal, maßen* oder *ossia*)

Comment: Tolle Methode, Kompliment!